# Exposing key/value pair in code block parameters

Tags: ruby, hash, codeblocks

Is it possible to expose the key/value pair from an array of hashes in the parameter of the block?

```
array = [{:a=>'a'}, {:b=>'b'}]                     # an array of hashes
array.each {|key, value| puts "#{key},#{value}"}   
array.map {|key, value| "(#{key},#{value})"}
array.inject([]) {|accum, (key,value)| key == :a ? value : accum}
```

Currently the results of the code block parameters |key, value| are (hash, nil) 
I would like to get (symbol, string) in the *declaration* of the |key,value| parameters.  Is this possible or am I stuck having to pass in a hash and extracting the key/value pair myself?

I know that passing a hash instead of an array will automatically give access to the key/value pair, but much of Ruby returns arrays.

UPDATE: It seems possible with arrays, but not hashes?

```
a = [['a','b'],['c','d']]
a.each {|(x,y)| puts "#{x}=>#{y}"}      # => a=>b
                                        # => c=>d
a.each {|x| p x}                        # => ["a", "b"]
                                        # => ["c", "d"]
```

Comment: Also, what's the question about? I read it 5 times and I still have no idea

Comment: mee to :))) no idea what op wants...

Comment: sorry, currently if I pass an array of hashes the code block parameters are (hash,nil).  I want to know if its possible to extract the key/value pair from the hash in the declaration of the code block parameters so that I don't have to do it myself in the code block.  I'm not sure if that explanation is any better.

Comment: Which block you're talking about? Also, there's no **the** pair in a hash. There can be many pairs and they are equal.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, as explained below I was hoping there was some automatic mechanism that could do it (I thought I saw in a book the use of parenthesis to expand values??). Evidently its not possible.

Comment: I posted an update with an array example that does expand. Is something similar possible with hashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. If I catch you wright :

```
array = [{:a=>'a'}, {:b=>'b'}]   
array.map {|k,v| [k,v]}
# => [[{:a=>"a"}, nil], [{:b=>"b"}, nil]]
```

you are getting above. But you want `[[:a,"a"], [:b,"b"]]` . No It is not possible. With `#each` or `#map`, when you have array of hashes like you given,you can't assign the block parameter `k,v` as `:a,"a"` and `:b,"b"` with each pass.

More simply try on your `IRB`,you will get to see the effect:

```
k,v = {:a=>'a'}
p k,v 

# >> {:a=>"a"}
# >> nil
```

Comment: Thanks, that is right. I was hoping there would be a better way, some automatic mechanism (I thought I remember reading in a book the use of parenthesis to expand values???).

Comment: I posted an update with an array example that does expand. Is something similar possible with hashes?